# Can't create Entities with custom entity manager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Symfony 6.2.1
PHP 8.1.2

I tried to create multible entity managers according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

content of **doctrine.yaml**

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            # configure these for your database server
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
        customer:
            # configure these for your database server
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOMER_URL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                Main:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                    alias: Main
        customer:
            connection: customer
            mappings:
                Customer:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customer'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Customer'
                    alias: Customer
```

When I try to generate a new entity with my second custom entity manager, it fails.

In my desperation I tried all of the following:

```
php bin/console make:entity customer
php bin/console make:entity Customer
php bin/console make:entity 'App\Entity\Customer'
php bin/console make:entity App\\Entity\\Customer
```

All I get is:

> Cannot find the entity manager for class
> "App\Entity\Customer"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `php bin/console make:entity 'App\Entity\Customer\Customer'`?

Comment: @Holicz Almost but not quite.  It needs to be an absolute path which means it starts with a leading backslash: `make:entity '\App\Entity\Customer\Customer' You can see what is going on in the MakerBundle\Generator::createClassNameDetails method.

Comment: And by the way, `make:entity 'Customer\Customer` will also work.  The quote marks are needed so the operating system does not mess with the backslash.  For relative paths the make bundle adds the `App\Entity` prefix.

Comment: Sorry, guys. This won't do. I don't want to create an entity named '...\...\customer' - I want to create an entity with the help of the entity manager named customer. These are two different things.

Comment: @Juergen I'm confused as usual.  Are you trying to make an actual instance of a Customer entity and persist it?  If so then `make:entity` is not going to help.  You can review the MakerBundle MakeEntity class to see what is going on.

Comment: So we are both confused. I am "just" asking how to use the second entity manager as stated in doctrine.yaml (with the second connection definition) to create a simple entity via "console make" - nothing more, nothing less. Or is there any other way to use multiple databases?

Comment: Your entity manager named Customer is configured to use whatever entities exist in the src/Entity/Customer directory with a namespace prefix of `App\Entity\Customer`.  The manager itself has no direct involvement in making the entity file.  You just need to tell the maker command the correct namespace to use.  There is no provision for telling the make:entity command to use the information from doctrine.yaml as a starting point.  Might be nice if there was.